# Local JavaScript Lib + Server-Side Web Page?

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Right now I'm writing an iPhone app that relies heavily on UIWebView. Each time this UIWebView is reloaded from server, it has to reload the entire JavaScript lib from server as well.

The JavaScript lib is like ~100KB in size. In a 3G environment, which is quite typical for a mobile app user, the UIWebView reloading process would last for at least 4 seconds, and is therefore unbearable.

My question is,

1. Is it possible for me to store the JavaScript lib in my app's local sandbox, and every time when I have to reload the UIWebView, I'll ask the UIWebView to reload everything from server but the JavaScript lib from local sandbox?
2. Or, is it possible for me to cache the JavaScript lib so I only have to load it once from server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this article to learn some about caching; I expect you'll find you can do everything you need with it.

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible with the HTML5 Cache Manifest:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html